# AngularJS: Minimal example with $resource and timeout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm struggling with a minimal example of a $resource timing out after a couple of seconds. Probably some stupid syntactic stuff.

Ok, here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/904dykrp/1/

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $resource, $timeout) {
    var url = "https://httpbin.org/delay/4";    // waits 4 seconds
    var myResource = $resource(url, {
        method: "get",
        timeout: 3000,  // 1) timeout after 3s -> gets ignored
        isArray: true,
        cancellable: true
    });
    $timeout(function() {
        // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource (at the bottom)
        myResource.$cancelRequest();    // 2) how do I cancel?
    }, 2000);

    myResource.get(function(response) {
        $scope.response = response;
    }, function(error) {
        // Here I want to do sth. with the cancelled request
        $scope.error = "Request took too long, cancelled. " + error;
    });
});
```

1) use $resource(...timeout: 3000). This gets ignored.

2) use $timeout to cancel the request after 2s. But $cancelRequest is unknown.

But unfortunately both requests to cancel my request don't work.

Can you help?

Thanks,
Bernhard

**Update** (Working example by georgeawg):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);  
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $resource, $timeout) {
    var url = "https://httpbin.org/delay/4";    // waits 4 seconds
    var myResource = $resource(url, {}, { 
      timedGet: {
        method: "get",
        timeout: 3000,
      },
    });
    var x = myResource.timedGet();
    x.$promise.then(function(response) {
       console.log(response)
       $scope.response = response;
    }, function(error) {
        // Here I want to do sth. with the cancelled request
           $scope.error = "Request took too long, cancelled. " + error;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) factory was malformed:

```
/* ERRONEOUS
var myResource = $resource(url, {
    method: "get",
    timeout: 3000,  // 1) timeout after 3s -> gets ignored
    isArray: true,
    cancellable: true
});
*/

//BETTER
var actions = {
  timedGet: {
    method: "get",
    timeout: 3000
  }
};    
var myResource = $resource(url, {}, actions);
```

Action methods are defined as the third argument of the factory. The second argument is for default parameters.

Usage:

```
var x = myResource.timedGet();
x.$promise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.response = response;
}, function(error) {
    // Here I want to do sth. with the cancelled request
    $scope.error = "Request took too long, cancelled. " + error;
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cng80q90/)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. As expected, I was close, but as it often happens for me and AngularJS, couldn't reach the finishing line ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was running across a similar situation and we eventually realized that this had to be accomplished on the server.  For our situation modifying the timeout on the server fixed the issue.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. I didn't think about that, but yes, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

> `timeout – {number}` – timeout in milliseconds. Note: In contrast to
>   `$http.config`, promises are not supported in `$resource`, because the
>   same value would be used for multiple requests. If you are looking for
>   a way to cancel requests, you should use the cancellable option.

Also you can read this article: http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/21666960.html